# PyQt6 how to get black menu bar in Mac OS Dark Mode

Tags: python, macos, qt6, pyqt6

I'm developing an app with PyQt6 for Mac OS. When using Dark Mode in the Mac OS settings it applies to all widgets etc in my app however for some reason the menubar does not turn black like it does for most other apps e.g. Google Chrome when running Mac OS in Dark Mode. I've noticed that the Finder app also does not get a black menubar for some reason.

Anyway, just wanted to check if anyone has successfully managed to get a black menu bar for their PyQt6 app when running in Mac OS Dark Mode?

I'm using Python 3.11 and Mac OS Ventura. I'm using PyInstaller to build the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Seems one only gets a black menu bar when running in full screen, which I was not doing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).